# Sending Dynamic value of selected dropdown to controller

Tags: javascript, html

I am fetching TopicName From the Controller through topicList array in my dropdown box and showing it to dropdown. what i want do is while sending back to the value of selected  dropdown i want to send the topicId (which is also store in topicList array) to the my controller through javascript function.
Here Is My Html code.
Select Topic:

```
      <td>
           <select name="Topic" id="Topic" class="myDropDown">
                     <option selected="selected" value="-1">-- Select Topic --</option>

                      <c:forEach var="item" items="${topicList}">
                         <option >${item.topicName} </option>
                       //Here I want to send the value of item.topicId`enter code here`
                       </c:forEach>
            </select>

      </td>
```

Here is my JavaScript Function through im sending my values
function doAddTopic(){

```
                         var subName=jq("#Topic option:selected").val();
                        // alert(name);aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

                    var url = "/xyz/abc/"+subName+"/";
                         jq.post(url, function(data) 
                       }
```

What i want is to on selecting item.topicName i want to send the value of item.topicId. how do i can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should try like this,

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${topicList}">
                         <option value="${item.topicId}">${item.topicName} </option>
                       //Here I want to send the value of item.topicId`enter code here`
                       </c:forEach>
```

Give value inside the option `value="${item.topicId}"`